# Is Dagger component bound to the object that instantiate it?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have been using Dagger 2 in my project. I understand that the lifetime of scoped object is the same as the lifetime of component (with the same scope). What about the lifetime of component then?

For example, I have a component:

```
@MyApp
@Component(modules = {
        ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    // Injection methods
    void inject(MyApplication mainApplication);
}
```

I build component by:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        buildApplicationComponent();
        mApplicationComponent.inject(this);
    }

    private void buildApplicationComponent() {
        mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Currently, the code to build component is in `Application` class. But 
is it so that if I build component in `Fragment` the `ApplicationComponent` would have the same lifetime as the fragment & if I execute it in `Application` class the component would have the same lifetime as the whole application? Or how the lifetime of component is defined?

Answer (score 0):

It is plain Java. You have object no matter where. The object provides you dependencies. If you use the same instance you will have the same dependencies or basically the same "Scope/lifetime". If you create somewhere new object it means new other object\dependencies it can provide so "another Scope/lifetime". If you share the object between different objects (You create it in the Application class, but reuse it in another fragment) you are in the "same Scope/lifetime".

But in general I see only "old way" of using Dagger 2 here. This is how your classes should end up everywhere. No need to find reference to any Components and etc or try to instantiate them on your own or clear them on your own in Fragments or Actvities. You have some code for Dagger 2 in one place and then some Annotations in you classes "which do the real work of your project". No need for complicated "connection" between the two parts and I see here a lot of cases like this which are part of tutorials that date back to 2016-2017...

```
class Repostory @Inject constructor(
private val dependency1: Dependency1 
) {}

class Activity or Fragment {
@Inject lateinit var dependency2: Dependency2
}
```

This is a great example for right usage of Dagger2.

https://github.com/google/iosched

Here is an article about the app:

https://medium.com/@JoseAlcerreca

Jose Alcerreca is one of the Google Lead Devs responsible for creating the guidelines to write Android apps.

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule { 
  @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class])
    internal abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

Just try to compile something like this. There is the exaxt same class in the app I gave you. Check the generated code and also the docs. If you see  ContributesAndroidInjector there is explained:

*Generates an {@link AndroidInjector} for the return type of this method. The injector is
implemented with a {@link dagger.Subcomponent} and will be a child of the {@link dagger.Module}'s component.*

If you check the AndroidInjector docs you will see that it is the one that is injectin the Activity. And there it will be the implementation:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {MainActivityModule.class})
  @ActivityScoped
  public interface MainActivitySubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity> {}
  }
```

So in general these annotations do the magic for you when a new activity starts. They create the Subcomponent, they use it and when the Activity Lifecycle ends the Subcomponent is also dead. Dagger clears the reference. Dagger knows how Activities work or Fragments and etc. There was the old way when you craete the component in the Activity, use it, call inject on your own. Or put some component in the AppClass and then clear it on your onw. But now there is a bigger amount of annotations.

Comment: But overall, what defines the lifetime length of a component instance? If a scoped provider provides an object, the lifetime of that object is bound with the component. But if thinking further, what defines component's lifetime?